# What happens to a destroyed creature with two totem armors on it?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a creature, with two different totem armors on it, and it's destroyed somehow (not sacrificed, not killed by -x,-x effects) what happens? Are both totem armors destroyed to save it, or just one? Can I choose which one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per [the Gatherer ruling](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=198304) (for Bear Umbra, not that it matters really):

> If a permanent you control is enchanted with multiple Auras that have
>   totem armor, and the enchanted permanent would be destroyed, one of
>   those Auras is destroyed instead -- but only one of them. You choose
>   which one because you control the enchanted permanent.

Comment: The comprehensive rule behind this Gatherer ruling is **616.1.** *If two or more replacement and/or prevention effects are attempting to modify the way an event affects an object or player, the affected object's controller (or its owner if it has no controller) or the affected player chooses one to apply, following the steps listed below.* — Since only one replacement effect "If enchanted permanent would be destroyed, instead remove all damage marked on it and destroy this Aura." is applied, the other aura isn't destroyed.